# JQuery Characters replace

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a textarea which contains huge text like this format

```
Question A    Answer A 
Question B   Answer B
Question C   Answer C
Question D   Answer D
```

Between Question and Answer it have Tab, and between answer and next question it have \n and tab.
I have some radio buttons for replacing this tab with any characters like comma, semi colon, colons etc 
I have tried this

```
$("textarea").html().replace("    ",",")
```

but its resplacing only first tabbed space.

Second I also want to replace \n with same characters(for this I have separate radio buttons)
I also have to sort the text area text in alphabetical order,How can I do this

Comment: Can you provide some real data?

Comment: http://quizlet.com/22168227/export/  this is the example

Comment: Are they actually tabs (`\t`) or you are passing four spaces in textarea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of TextArea, you need to use `val()` instead of `.html()` to consider `\n` or `\t`.

```
var value = $("textarea").val().replace(/\t/g,",");  
//use the variable "value" to store it again in textarea or for further process.
```

**UPDATE**:

```
var value = $("textarea").val().split('    ').join(',');  //or '\t'
$("textarea").val(value);
```

Comment: still its replacing only first one

Comment: you need to store the result in a variable to use it further. I hope you are doing that.

Comment: @SyedSalmanRazaZaidi I updated it again. if this doesn't work then please post the string in your post.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use RegEx and specify global flag:

```
$("textarea").val( $("textarea").val().replace(/\s{2,}/g,",") );
```

this is for arbitrary number of spaces, more or equal then 2

Comment: still its replacing only first one

Comment: I guess you are not setting result back in element: $("textarea").html($("textarea").html().replace(/    /g,","));

Comment: I am setting it, but its replacing only first tab

Comment: Maybe number of spaces is an issue, and only first one has this number of them?

Comment: number of spaces are same, but in case of others they first have \n (after anwers) I think that's the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("textarea").html().replace(/\s/g, ",");  // to replace all spaces
$("textarea").html().replace(/\n/g, ",");   // to replace all newline chars
```

where g = global flag

Comment: `\s` would replace spaces in the question and answers, I guess he wants to replace only `tabs` and `newlines`

Comment: its replacing spaces, but its adding multiple ,

Comment: @BrunoLM does `.html()` work here? that's the main issue in this post I think.

Comment: @Mr_Green well, it works http://jsfiddle.net/m2CUU/ But sure I wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: ya @BrunoLM i think i misread the question and .replace(/\t/g, ",") will work and should use val() instead of html()